# Generating MigrationHistory table in reverse engineered code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have reverse engineered on existing database for code first. Next i Enabled-Migrating for the context (Code based migration). When i create an initial add-migration it works fine and would apply on an empty database.
But my requirement is that i need to use the same database i used for creating the models because of the data it has.

Now the conundrum is how do i implement the code based migrations. My database does not have a migration history table. So, when i run Update-database, it tries to create the existing tables and fails.

How can i capture the current state in the migration history or instruct EF to create the migration history with the current schema as the starting point.

Do i need to turn on the automatic migration for initial setup. Please suggest.

**Note**: I am using EF 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish a baseline migration of the existing items. So the first migration you create should be:

`add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges`

The ignore changes tells EF to just save a snapshot of the current database. Now any subsequent migrations will not include the existing tables (just the changes). This would allow you to continue updating your existing database since EF will see the record in __MigrationHistory or deploy to a new, empty database.

See the [under the hood section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn481501).

Comment: If I want to use this script on another database that doesn't have the __migration table, how do I do it?

Comment: @NicolasBelley Use `update-database -Script`. Then you can run that script through SSMS or [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility).

Comment: if I do that, it says there are no pending changes and also after it fails with Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled.

Comment: @NicolasBelley Just to be clear, you want a script to create a completely new database somewhere else? In that case, you need to specify the initial migration: `update-database -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase -Script`. If that fails, start a new question and post the link.

Comment: No, I found this answer after I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118820/ef-code-first-with-existing-database-on-another-database) I had an existing DB, activated code first migrations on it, so I had an empty Initial. Now, I have another DB which is the same as the original one, but not migration activated yet, I don't know how to do it...